# Request query from multiple dynamic checkboxes with Spark

Tags: java, freemarker, spark-java

I have an html list of checkboxes which is dynamically created with **Freemarker**. The Html looks like this:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Software</h4>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
        <ul data-role="listview" >
            <#list softwareoptions as software>
                <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="${software}" autocomplete="off" >${software}
            </#list>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here's the generated list:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
<h4>Software</h4>
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <ul data-role="listview" >
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Adobe Creative Cloud" autocomplete="off" >Adobe Creative Cloud
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Adobe Web Premium" autocomplete="off" >Adobe Web Premium
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="MATLAB" autocomplete="off" >MATLAB
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Quicken" autocomplete="off" >Quicken
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Steam" autocomplete="off" >Steam
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="IBM SPSS Statistics" autocomplete="off" >IBM SPSS Statistics
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft SQL Server 2008" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft SQL Server 2008
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft SQL Server 2012" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft SQL Server 2012
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft Office" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft Office
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Autodesk Infrastructure Design Suite" autocomplete="off" >Autodesk Infrastructure Design Suite
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft Visual Studio 2010" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft Visual Studio 2013" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft Visual Studio 2015" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft Visual Studio 2015
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft Visio" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft Visio
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Unity 3d" autocomplete="off" >Unity 3d
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="GIMP" autocomplete="off" >GIMP
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Maxon CINEMA 4D Broadcast" autocomplete="off" >Maxon CINEMA 4D Broadcast
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="CrazyBump" autocomplete="off" >CrazyBump
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="FRAPS" autocomplete="off" >FRAPS
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="InfraRecorder" autocomplete="off" >InfraRecorder
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Garageband" autocomplete="off" >Garageband
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Microsoft Project" autocomplete="off" >Microsoft Project
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Numbers" autocomplete="off" >Numbers
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Pages" autocomplete="off" >Pages
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Fontographer" autocomplete="off" >Fontographer
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Keynote" autocomplete="off" >Keynote
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Wacom Tablet" autocomplete="off" >Wacom Tablet
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Arduino" autocomplete="off" >Arduino
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="iBooks" autocomplete="off" >iBooks
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="iMovie" autocomplete="off" >iMovie
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="Logic Pro X" autocomplete="off" >Logic Pro X
            <input type="checkbox" id="softwarefilter" name="softwarefilter" value="iTunes" autocomplete="off" >iTunes
    </ul>
</form>
</div>
```

To request values of the check boxes I use Java code:

```
Object softstring = request.queryParams("softwarefilter");
```

However this only returns the string value of the name of the first check box which is checked. For example, if Adobe Creative Suite and MATLAB are checked, softstring = "Adobe Creative Suite".

When I use:

```
 Object softstring = request.queryParamsValues("softwarefilter");
```

or

```
QueryParamsMap softmap = request.queryMap("softwarefilter");
```

I get an empty array and a null map respectively. Any hints as to what I might be missing?

Comment: You have put a `<label>` directly inside `<ul>` which is likely to be incorrect markup

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, I'll remove it though.

Comment: Which version of Spark you use? You send form by GET or POST? Show HTML generated by FreeMarker and more Java code.

Comment: I'm using spark 2.3. I know its work on some level, since the page returns the value of the first box which is checked, just not all of them.

Comment: Having the same id to all inputs is wrong. All checkbox inputs must have the same name, not the same id. It may not affect the behaviour you mention, but it is bad practice and unnecessary.

Comment: I reproduced your example like @vandershraaf wrote and `queryParamsValues` works fine, but your `queryMap` invocation is invalid. Try `request.queryMap().toMap().get("softwarefilter")` - this returns `String[]`. Maybe there is a problem with sending form to server. Do you post it by simple form or maybe AJAX?

Answer (score 2):

I used the same HTML codes as in the question, except that I added a submit tag into the form.

Based on inspection, all the options selected are in the form data part.

[image]

As such, the options can be retrieved from `req.body();` For example, if I select 'Adobe Creative Cloud' and 'Adobe Web Premium', the output from `req.body();` is

```
softwarefilter=Adobe+Creative+Cloud&softwarefilter=Adobe+Web+Premium
```

Now it is the matter of parsing this raw string to get all the options selected. Hope this helps.